# How to see localhost in my smart phone with android and ios operating system

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, localhost

my pc connected to my modem by lan and i have access to the internet by lan.
but my android device connected to my modem via WIFI and it's have access to the internet too.
my pc local ip is : 192.168.1.2 and my android device ip is : 192.168.1.3
PC : Use Lan.
Phone : Use Wifi.
i think pc and phone is in the same network .
what i want to do : I am running angular 2 application and ionic 2 mobile application on my pc under localhost with this url:http://localhost:8100
my question is this : how can i see my localhost into my android device?
i get nothing in my android device.
please help me with your solution thanks.

Comment: Did you try http://192.168.1.2:8100 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access using your PC's ip address by typing it on the browser

```
192.168.1.2
```

Try to indicate the port too if that doesnt work

Answer (score 3):

you can serve your application on your ip. then you can access it on your phone using that ip.

```
ng serve --host 192.168.1.2
```

or

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check
```

Comment: thank you so much.this solution solved my problem.booos

Comment: Looks like OP mistakenly marked my answer as correct.